# Entity Framework Non-nullable column is mapped to a nullable entity property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mapping, poco, nullable

I am getting this nullable column error message in Entity Framework 4.1 - when the column is not actually nullable:

```
Non-nullable column MyView.RunningTotal in table TransactionListView 
is mapped to a nullable entity property.
```

But you can see from the screenshots below that the column is not nullable and that the entity property is not nullable either.  So why is this error occurring?

[image]

Comment: Doesn't (None) mean the default value of nullability but not false? If you specify True, will it work? I have no visual studio near me now to check by myself...

Comment: Changing (None) to False works, but that change will be lost every time the edmx is regenerated (using generate model from database)

Comment: Have you tried removing the entity from the designer and re-adding it?  I've solve similar issues this way.

Comment: @JK - No, it won't be lost.  EF does not change properties that are already set.

Comment: try changing options on model generation - there is a place there where you can adjust this behaviour.

Comment: @Ilya that seems to work - if you want to change you comment to an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The straight-forward solution is to manually specify Nullable parameter to True.

Comment: Ok, so I did this to begin with and I'm still getting this error in Visual Studio 2015. Something is wrong.

Comment: It's so weird. In the properties window, it said nullable "True", but I just opened the .edmx file in a text editor and it's set to false. What the heck.

Comment: @JaredBeach, same thing was happening to me. Turns out, when you update the .edmx file, you need to save it (ctrl + s) before the changes manifest in the partial classes! Big surprise for me!

Answer (score 0):

2017 Update (Visual Studio 2017)

If the accepted straight-forward solution mentioned by lLya didn't help you, then this might.
You may notice that when you save a diagram it does some work, like changing the class properties according to your diagram changes. One would think that the generator itself would be aware of these changes, right?! You might still get this error.

What fixed it for me was regenerating the database (right click in diagram -> Regenerate Database from Model).